# Show the context menu on icon?

Tags: javascript, user-interface, contextmenu, webix

I have a Webix datatable

```
webix.ui({
  view:"datatable", id:"dtable", data:grid_data,
  columns:[
    {id:"title", adjust:true},
    {id:"more", template:"<icon class='webix_icon fa-cog'></icon>"}
  ]
});
```

with the attached context menu

```
webix.ui({
  view:"contextmenu",
  data:["More info",  "Edit", "Delete record"],
  click:function(id, context){
    webix.message(id+" on row "+this.getContext().id);
  }
}).attachTo( $$("dtable") );
```

Here's my [snippet](http://webix.com/snippet/6d6b8e97)

Wondering is it possible to show the context menu on only on the icon? Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Webix documentation you'll find [onBeforeContextMenu](http://docs.webix.com/api__link__ui.datatable_onbeforecontextmenu_event.html) event. Using it, you can check the column id and prevent showing of the context menu on other columns:

```
on:{
    onBeforeContextMenu:function(id, e, node){
        if (id.column !== "more")
            return false;
    }
}
```

In your snippet, the column contains only icons, so this solution can suit your needs. As an addition, I suggest you prevent the browser context on the datatable via

```
webix.event($$("dtable").$view, "contextmenu", function(e){  
    webix.html.preventEvent(e);
});
```

http://webix.com/snippet/509f218d